# Gravity Forms: Action-hook gform_field_standard_settings

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm new to Gravity Forms.

At https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_standard_settings/ one finds an example to create a new standard setting for "Single Line Text" fields on the field’s General tab.
I tried to change it and it worked well.

But: I tried to create such a custom setting for an other of the provided fields, such as "Paragraph Text" or "Number" or so, but failed.

And: I wondered, there is no indication whatsoever in the above example code that says particularly that it applies "Single Line Text" - but it does and I don't understand why and how.